# Is there a general stability result for the linear delay differential equation $x'(t)=Ax(t)+Bx(t-\tau)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, delay-differential-equations

Is there a general stability result for the linear delay differential equation $x'(t)=Ax(t)+Bx(t-\tau)$ where $A$ and $B$ are $m\times m$ matrices?  If not, is there a current summary of the known stability conditions?  As of 2007, I believe the answer was no.  Matsunaga had a nice summary in a 2007 paper titled, "Exact stability criteria for delay differential and difference equations" that specified:

[image: stability of delay differential equations as of 2007]

I was unable to locate a more recent survey and didn't know if better criteria had been found since that publication.